# Updating to nodejs 4x MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, redhat, mean-stack, meanjs, devops

So I've been using node v 0.10x and 0.12x for dev  and prod environments.
Now we need to upgrade to v4x and as I'm doing so, I'm finding that is not so easy, gcc compiler issues, deprecated libs...

Here are some of the messages I'm getting 
    [image: Deprecated libs]
    [image: kerberos Mongodb]
    [image: sikpping Optional libs]

I was able to overcome the c++11 problems

- [Updating to Node.js 4](https://developer.ibm.com/open/2015/11/17/updating-to-node-v4-there-will-be-hiccups/)
- [Node on old distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/OLDER_DISTROS.md)

Now what I would like is to have the builds as clean as possible,
as well as to know what is the impact of having this deprecated libraries in the project in the short/long term,
is it possible to completely get rid of them? if so is there a kind of best practices approach for this?

For instance I updated lodash@1.0.2 to version 4 in the main package.json file just to find/get more deprecated libraries like a nested deprecated libraries, so is it really possible to get rid of this deprecated libraries?
    [image: More Deprecated libs]

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from v0.1 to v.0.2, you need create a [node link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) between the local and the global modules.

About the `warnings`,

`npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8`

Don-t be afraid about the after update all the packages, some packages are marked as deprecated but the doesn't have any update available, then if you tried update them, don't worry, that doesn't affect your project.

And releated with the last of your issues: 
`UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY kerberos@~0.0`

First one you need update your kerberos development package:

`apt-get install libkrb5-dev`

And running the command:

`npm install --save kerberos mongod`

If that doesn't fix your issue, you could try in a manual way intall all the packages with:

`git clone https://github.com/christkv/kerberos.git
cd kerberos
npm install
npm install -g node-gyp
cd ~/JesusTheProject
npm install mongodb --save
npm --loglevel verbose install mongodb`